# haproxy permanently down (health check)

Tags: haproxy

We are conducting a service test using Docker Swarm and Haproxy.

Health Check works when the service is alive, but when the web service is arbitrarily killed in the docker and the backend is down, the health check is never done in Happy again.

I want to do Health Check when the web service comes back to life after it dies.

My config file

```
global
    daemon

defaults
    log       global
    mode      http
    option    http-server-close
    timeout   http-request  10s
    timeout   client        20s
    timeout   connect       4s
    timeout   server        30s
    timeout   http-keep-alive   10s

frontend www
    bind *:80

    default_backend web-svr

backend web-svr

    option  httpchk HEAD /ping 

    server  server1   backend_server:8000  check fall 3 rise 2
```

server up status

[server up status](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YQ3fH.png)

server down status (The server is down even after an hour. After the server is shut down, Haproxy will not ping the server even if it is running again.
)

[server down status](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vRX2e.png)

------------ add screenshot -----------

server kill after screenshot

[server kill after screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d7wWr.png)

server re run(When you send a ping, logs are accumulated, but the ping does not come.)

[server re run logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cQwrj.png)

2 minutes have passed since the server is down

[server down 2min](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z6ftU.png)

Comment: There's nothing here to suggest the backend isn't being checked.

Comment: I can't access the website. 
And there's a screenshot of the server state in the article.

Comment: Your screenshot shows it has been down for 1 second and the check interval is 2 seconds.  Assuming you did restart the site within that one second, you need to wait another second for a check.  The HTTP logs need to be reproduced to see what is happening, not a screenshot at a particular instance in time.

Comment: I'm sorry. The example is wrong. That down time stays the same after an hour.

Comment: Can you replace the status screen with one taken when HaProxy was running for a bit longer than 62 seconds?

Comment: okay wait a minute

Comment: @GerardH.Pille   I uploaded a screenshot

Comment: I see the L4TOUT, so HaProxy can't even connect to that server.  What is your OS?

Comment: Is "backend_server" a name or an IP address?

Comment: Are using amazone linux2 
backend_server is host name and  i used docker swarm

Comment: So this could be an amazon or docker problem. You chose a very complex environment.

Comment: The problem was solved by referencing the docker dns using Haproxy resolvers.